# Unable to include timespec in another struct

Tags: c, struct

I've read many posts on this and I can tell you (every post I've read makes this set of assumptions, so lets get it out of way early):

- I have included time.h appropriately
- I have specified both the POSIX constants and -std=gnu99

Code:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <linux/soundcard.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define uint unsigned int

struct KEYDATA 
{
   struct timestruct duration; 
} ;

// output/display function
int main(void) 
{
   struct KEYDATA keyData[20]; 

   keyData.duration.tv_nsec = 999;   

   return 0;
}
```

At compile time:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/src/midi-timing $ gcc tmp.c -O2 -Wall -pedantic -o tmp -std=gnu99 -lrt
tmp.c:19:22: error: field ‘duration’ has incomplete type
    struct timestruct duration; 
                      ^
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:27:11: error: request for member ‘duration’ in something not a structure or union
    keyData.duration.tv_nsec = 999;   
           ^
tmp.c:25:19: warning: variable ‘keyData’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    struct KEYDATA keyData[20]; 
                   ^
pi@raspberrypi:~/src/midi-timing $
```

I'll admit I'm a little rusty on my C programming, but there must be something here I'm not seeing.   If you see the error, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `struct timespec` (defined in [`<time.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html); has nanosecond resolution and member `tv_nsec`) or `struct timeval` (defined in [`<sys/time.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html); has microsecond resolution and member `tv_usec`, and is more or less deprecated)?  I assume `struct timestruct` is a typo for `struct timespec`.

Comment: You might note that the question title correctly identifies `struct timespec`; it is simply a question of not carrying that thought through to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've identified the type of `duration` as `struct timestruct` instead of `struct timespec`. Simply fix this misspelling and I believe you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I must have been looking at it for a bit too long yesterday.  Not only is that the primary error, but I also needed to index the array in setting the tv_nsec variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `timestruct` with `timespec`

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <linux/soundcard.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define uint unsigned int

struct KEYDATA 
{
       //struct timestruct duration; 
      struct timespec duration;
} ;

// output/display function
int main(void) 
{
   struct KEYDATA keyData[20]; 

   //keyData.duration.tv_nsec = 999; 
   keyData->duration.tv_nsec = 999;   

   return 0;
}
```